# how to change order of NSMutable array in same way another mutable arrays get changed

Tags: ios, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have three `arrays`. They are *name*, *birthdates* and *remaining* days like below:

```
    name                         birthdate                 remaining 

    "Abhi Shah",                 "01/14",                  300
    "Akash Parikh",              "12/09/1989",             264
    "Anand Kapadiya",            "12/01",                  256
    "Annabella Faith Perez",     "03/02",                  347
    "Aysu Can",                  "04/14/1992",             25
    "Chirag Pandya"              "10/07/1987"              201
```

I want to rearrange the *remaining* days `array` into ascending order,
but at the same time *name* and *birthdate* should also get reordered in the same way.

See this example below:

```
    name                         birthdate                 remaining 

    "Aysu Can",                  "04/14/1992",             25
    "Chirag Pandya"              "10/07/1987"              201
    "etc..."
```

Comment: It's called **Object**-oriented programming for a reason ;-) Create an object that holds those 3 variables and get rid of your multi array reordering mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    self.arrayForRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *arrayForNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Abhi Shah",@"Akash",@"Nagavendra",@"Ramana",@"Simhachalam", nil];
    NSMutableArray *arrayForBirthDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"01/14/94",@"01/14",@"11/07/87",@"12/07/89",@"23/08/91", nil];
    NSMutableArray *arrayForRemaining = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"200",@"320",@"32",@"450",@"14", nil];


    for (int i=0; i<arrayForBirthDates.count; i++)
    {
       NSMutableDictionary *tempDicts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
       [tempDicts setObject:[arrayForNames objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"names"];
       [tempDicts setObject:[arrayForBirthDates objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"birth"];
       [tempDicts setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[arrayForRemaining objectAtIndex:i] intValue]] forKey:@"remaining"];
       [self.arrayForRows addObject:tempDicts];
    }  


    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"remaining" ascending:YES];
    [self.arrayForRows sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

**Use this in tableView listing**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.arrayForRows count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifer = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.arrayForRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"names"];
    return cell;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: dic get created but it not getting sort with NSSortDEscriptor whats wrong?

Comment: It is working for me fine. how you are accessing in your cellForRowAtIndexpath method ? could you tell me ?, see my edited answer

Comment: CellForRowAtIndexPath is later thing  when i NSLOG arrayForRows after ur code then still it remain the way it was, array of dic do not get ordered in ascending order

Comment: I am getting it yar perfectly. You just copy and paste my code and tried ??

Comment: just forget about table view right now, we made dictionary right within that for loop and same time we are adding in our array.  now our array is having Dic now when we use that NSsortDiscriptor then its  not ordering it in Ascending order

Comment: ones it will get ordered then yes i will show it table view but first we need to order it in accordance to "remaining" key

Comment: Got your point.. Now check i had updated the code.. It will work fine

Comment: let me see check Manohar :)

Comment: wow wow wow my man Manohar. it worked now got it NSSortDescriptor work with NSNumber it was string we needed intiger ha ha thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

use `NSMutableDictionary` to store data to `NSMutableArray`

```
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 for (int i=0; i<totalRows; i++)
 {
        NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic setValue:[array_1 objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"names"];
        [dic setValue:[array_2 objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"birthdate "];
        [dic setValue:[array_3 objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"remanning"];
        [array addObject:dic];
        [dic release];
 }
```

here after you arrange name array,use search option to use name not use index and
use `NSPredicate` search data in `NSMutableArray`

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"names matches[cd] %@", name];
 NSArray *result = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
 NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[[result objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy] autorelease];
 NSLog(@"%@",dict);// result
```

Comment: i dont understand this predicate will you explain how it going to sort?

Comment: it not sort array it get particular dic in array,you sort only name array,using sorted name array and use predicate to get particular name details in array

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"names matches[cd] %@", name];  here  names is a key and name is searching user name

Answer (score 2):

once try like this it'l help you,

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setObject:@"rahul" forKey:@"name"];
    [dict setObject:@"10" forKey:@"value"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict1 setObject:@"ttt" forKey:@"name"];
    [dict1 setObject:@"6" forKey:@"value"];

    NSMutableArray *ar=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [ar addObject:dict];
    [ar addObject:dict1];

    NSSortDescriptor *Sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    [ar sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:Sorter]];
    NSLog(@"---%@",ar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put each row into a dictionary, and out those dictionaries into an array. Then sort your away using a predicate or sort block. If you want an array containing just the sorted names for example, you could use `[ array valueForKeyPath:@"name" ]`

Array looks like:

```
[
    { @"name" : ..., 
        @"birthdate" : ...birthdate..., 
        @"remaining" : ...days remaining... } ,
    {...},
    {...}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

such as your `MutableArray` is a `Dictionarys array` , you can use `sortUsingComparator`
 to sort the array

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    int a = [(NSNumber *)[(NSDictionary *)obj1 objectiveForKey: @"remanning"] intValue];
    int b = [(NSNumber *)[(NSDictionary *)obj2 objectiveForKey: @"remanning"] intValue];

    if (a < b) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if(a == b)
    {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
    return NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

For example , I have a test :

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@(30),@(20),@(5),@(100), nil];

[array sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    int a = [(NSNumber *)obj1 intValue];
    int b = [(NSNumber *)obj2 intValue];

    if (a < b) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if(a == b)
    {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
    return NSOrderedDescending;
}];

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@ , %d",obj,idx);
}];
```

then the output is :
[image]

Comment: what about names and birthdates array how they will get changed in same way the changes are happening in remain array?

Comment: @user2189388 you should make a person is a `Dictionary` or a `Class`  such as , `persion1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Abhi Shah",@"01/14",@(300),@"names",@"birthdate",@"remanning", nil];` `array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:persion1,persion2,persion3,..., nil]`