# adding array in NSDictionary and ordering it

Tags: ios

i have three array like below

```
names                      birthdate                remanning 

"Abhi Shah",                 "01/14",                  300
"Akash Parikh",              "12/09/1989",             264
"Anand Kapadiya",            "12/01",                  256
"Annabella Faith Perez",     "03/02",                  347
"Aysu Can",                  "04/14/1992",             25
"Chirag Pandya"              "10/07/1987"              201
```

plz it will be great help if you give me code for how to add this three array in NSDictionary and then after ordering(ascending) whole dictionary in accordance to "remaning" array

Note in Dic everything should get changed. not only remaning array.  names and birthdate should get changed in same way remaning days are getting changed

thank you so much in advance

Comment: u want to sorta ccording to remaining days?

Comment: you add same question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517015/how-to-change-order-of-nsmutable-array-in-same-way-another-mutable-arrays-get-ch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take each record (names, birthdate, remanning ) in the dictionary or any structure. And array of that dictionary should be created. To sort the array as per your requirement any sorting mechanism can be used.

```
-(void)sort
{
    //This is the array of dictionaries, where each dictionary holds a record
    NSMutableArray * array; 
    //allocate the memory to the mutable array and add the records to the arrat

    // I have used simple bubble sort you can use any other algorithm that suites you
    //bubble sort
    //
    for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j < [array count]; j++)
        {
            NSDictionary *recordOne = [array objectAtIndex:i];
            NSDictionary *recordTwo = [array objectAtIndex:j];

            if([[recordOne valueForKey:@"remaining"] integerValue] > [[recordTwo valueForKey:@"remaining"] integerValue])
            {
                [array xchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:j];
            }
        }   
    }

    //Here you get the sorted array
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise you to **change the design** of your project and  **create a model** for same as having properties :

```
@interface YourModel : NSObject
    @property (strong) NSString *name;
    @property (strong) NDDate *birthDate;
    @property NSInteger remaining;
@end
```

And then create an NSMutableArray in your class, and go on to add them.

This will make your work easier, as searching, sorting, filtering , than handling 3 parallel arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the design proposed by Anoop, the sorting code using blocks would be something similar to this:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSInteger first = [(YourModel*)a remaining];
    NSInteger second = [(YourModel*)b remaining];
    return [first compare:second];
}];
```